# Spring Batch 5 With Scheduler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I'd like to make a new project with Spring Batch 5.
There is already existing project with Spring Web based on `@Scheduled` annotation, and I'd like to convert that business logics to Spring Boot 5.

Here's my fundamental question

- Is it possible to launch the job periodically like once a day at 0:00 am?
  -> Yes, as I've searched, but I'm struggling with building a Spring Batch 5 project with Scheduling.

I've tried to search tutorials for this task for a week, but I couldn't find what I want.
I attach the source code of the `OpenApiJob.class` (Please ignore the Korean letters)

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OpenApiJob {

    // Job build 및 순서 정의
    @Bean
    public Job hospitalDataJob(Step step, JobRepository jobRepository) {
        return new JobBuilder("myJob",jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope    // JobParameter를 보내므로 설정
    public Step openApiFristStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("myStep", jobRepository)
                .<HospitalFullDataResponse.HospitalItem[], HospitalFullDataResponse.HospitalItem[]>chunk(1, transactionManager) // Input, Output, chunk 사이즈
                .reader(openApiReader())
                .processor(dataEditProcessor())
                .writer(dataInsertWrite())
                .build();
    }

    // 데이터를 읽어오는 ItemReader 인터페이스의 커스텀 구현체
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public OpenApiReader openApiReader(){
        return new OpenApiReader();
    }

    // 읽어온 데이터를 가공 후 반환하는 ItemProcessor 인터페이스의 커스텀 구현체
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public OpenApiProcessor dataEditProcessor() {
        return new OpenApiProcessor();
    }

    // 가공 되어진 데이터들(Chunk)를 DB 혹은 특정 파일에 작성하는 ItemWriter 인터페이스의 커스텀 구현체
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public OpenApiWriter dataInsertWrite() {
        return new OpenApiWriter();
    }
}
```

How can I run `hospitalDataJob` with scheduling? As far as I searched, I may need to implement the JobLauncher, but I really cannot find how to do that.

Any recommendations and answers will be helpful.

There is already existing project with Spring Web based on `@Scheduled` annotation, and I'd like to convert that business logics to Spring Boot 5. But I don't know how to launch the job periodically.

#1 update

I attach further more information about the project.

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  batch:
    jdbc:
      schema: classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql
      initialize-schema: always
    job:
      enabled: false
```

`BatchApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

Comment: Inject the `JobLauncher` into your component that does the scheduling, as well as the `Job` you want to schedule. Then just call the proper methods. You don't need to implement a `JobLauncher` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to implement a `JobLauncher`. You can define a scheduled method that runs periodically according to the required schedule and launch the job in it using the built-in `JobLauncher`. Here is an example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "* 10 * * * *") // define schedule as needed
    public void runJob(@Autowired JobLauncher jobLauncher, @Autowired Job job) throws Exception {
        JobParameters parameters = new JobParameters();
        // add parameters as needed
        jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much with very practical source code. I figured out to set scheduler but I've met another problem though hahahaha