# How can I make multiple job in Spring Batch 5?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

in my previous question, I solved how to set the scheduling for a job.
[Spring Batch 5 With Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76658286/spring-batch-5-with-scheduler/76659931#76659931)

I'd like to write multiple jobs in one Spring Batch project.
The structure would be like this

```
A job
- A1 step
-- A1 reader
-- A1 processor
-- A1 writer

B job
- B1 step
-- B1 reader
-- B1 processor
-- B1 writer
- B2 step
-- B2 reader
-- B2 processor
-- B2 writer
```

I want to compose several jobs in one project, and I want to make them work periodically each other through the cron. (Like `@Scheduled`)

I'm struggling with making the project a week, so is there anyone who tell me the proper way or documents?  (I've found some examples for Spring Batch 4, but it's very hard to find the information for Spring Batch 5)

I want to compose several jobs in one project, and I want to make them work periodically each other through the cron. -> Using cron with single job is working now, but I don't know how to configure several Jobs on a same project.)

Comment: Write the jobs, create the schedules. It is no different as it was with Spring Batch 4 and no more complex then you describe. So what is the issue you are actually running into?

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for adding a comment. I'd like to distribute Jobs into different class, but I meet ```A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/care/batch/core/job/BasicJobConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.``` this kind of error as I put ```@Configuration``` annotation in two different classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum Should I put the all jobs and steps inside a single class which has ```@Configuration``` in Spring Batch?

Comment: You should have 1 class that configures Spring Batch, then a configuration per job.